# SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue of multi-binded wpf combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I'm kind of new to wpf templating and binding, and that's why have faced up with the following issue:

Let's assume that I have following objects in my application.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboModel" Width="230" Height="25" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"         HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                     <TextBlock.Text>
                      <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}: {2}-{3}">
                       <Binding Path="ModelName"/>
                       <Binding Path="ModelBody"/>
                       <Binding Path="ModelFromYear"/>
                       <Binding Path="ModelToYear"/>
                      </MultiBinding>
                     </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                   </DataTemplate>
         </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

**CODE:** Combobox is bound to List of ModelYearClass objects.

```
public class ModelYearClass
{
    private string modelName;
    public string ModelName
    {
        get { return modelName; }
        set
        {
            modelName = value;
        }
    }
    private string modelMake;
    public string ModelMake
    {
        get { return modelMake; }
        set
        {
            modelMake = value;
        }
    }
    private string modelBody;
    public string ModelBody
    {
        get { return modelBody; }
        set
        {
            modelBody = value;
        }
    }
    private string modelYear;
    public string ModelYear
    {
        get { return modelYear; }
        set
        {
            modelYear = value;
        }
    }
    private int modelId;
    public int ModelId
    {
        get { return modelId; }
        set
        {
            modelId = value;
        }
    }
    private string modelFromYear;
    public string ModelFromYear
    {
        get { return modelFromYear; }
        set
        {
            modelFromYear = value;
        }
    }
    private string modelToYear;
    public string ModelToYear
    {
        get { return modelToYear; }
        set
        {
            modelToYear = value;
        }
    }
}
    ...
    List<ModelYearClass> ModelYearList;
    ...
    ComboModel.ItemsSource = ModelYearList;
    ComboModel.SelectedValuePath = "@ModelId";
    ComboModel.SelectedValue = 2;
```

Everything is fine - the combobox is populated with what I want, but I'm not able to assign a value I need, by these lines.

```
ComboModel.SelectedValuePath = "@ModelId";
ComboModel.SelectedValue = 2;
```

I think maybe it's done somehow else for a combobox with multibindig?

How to achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing the `@` from `"@ModelId"` works for me.

```
ComboModel.SelectedValuePath = "ModelId";
```

Usually the `SelectedValuePath` property of a `ComboBox` never changes. If so, consider setting it in XAML.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="ModelId" ... >
...
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I've tried removing "@" but it does not help, moreover after removing I can't see the item values in combo though combo is populated.

Comment: I've found that combo item values dissapear only when I do ComboModel.SelectedValue = 2; a bit strange behaviour..any ideas?

Comment: @khurshed_nosirov Are you sure there's a `ModelYearClass` instance where `ModelId = 2` in that list? What's the value of `ModelYearList.Count(m => m.ModelId == 2);` when you assign `ItemsSource` on the `ComboBox`?

Comment: You were absolutely right! Also my trouble was because of SelectionChanged="ComboModel_SelectionChanged_1" this event was making a mess in everything. I forgot to include it in my post, however it was in my code. Thank you man, appreciate it!